# HTML button element - svg image inside - weird gap & positioning

Tags: html, css, button, svg, css-position

I have the following HTML:

```
<button class="button">
  <img src="img/menu-2.svg">
</button>
```

And this CSS:

```
.button {
    padding: 0;
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

When I inspect the button with Firebug I can see that there is still some kind of weird gap between the image and the border of the button. Is there anyway to remove this? I would like the image to fill out the button as much as possible, or at least be centered.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Or maybe its something with the SVG file? This is the SVG code that should influence the positioning:

```
x="0px" y="0px" width="44px" height="44px" viewBox="0 0 44 44" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16"
```

What strikes me is `enable-background`, but I don't know what it does & removing it did nothing.

Comment: Do you have the SVG image somewhere online?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Sure, its the menu icon from Adam Whitcroft's "Batch" icon set. I pasted it into a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WhLDT/ (Note how I changed the 48px to 48px while debugging).

Comment: When you saved your svg files did you save white space on the canvas or is the canvas size only containing the icon and nothing else?

Comment: Looks fine to me using chrome

Comment: @Sven Just to be sure, is the class in your HTML `button` or is it `menu-button`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Sorry, its `menu-button`. That happens when you simplify things ;-) I'll correct it now!

Comment: @JoshPowell I don't know as I don't saved the file. Is there any way to find out? Also note it's SVG, so I am not even sure if there is something like "canvas" as its just shapes & paths.

Comment: @Sven This might be some Firefox thing. I've set a background on `button` and tested your SVG image button with Firefox and Chromium. With Firefox the image seems to be shifted, but with Chromium it looks fine, no border or shifting.

Comment: @Sven, If you open up the svg file in illustrator you will find out if there is extra whitespace on the canvas. I'm almost 100% sure that is what's causing the problem.

Comment: @JoshPowell Wow, you were right, just checked it! I just re-saved it and now it works, wow. If you could post this as an answer please? Thanks everyone who commented!

Comment: I just finished posting the answer for you!

Comment: `enable-background` is related to SVG filters.  If you are not using any filters, it is safe to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving an svg you will want to make sure your artwork contains the entire canvas board so there is not white space in the final image.

http://healthbenefitsohio.com/images/svg_whitespace.jpg

Based on the image above, you would have extra spacing on the top, left, and bottom which would cause some awkward spacing.

http://healthbenefitsohio.com/images/svg_nospace.jpg

The image above shows the proper way to save an svg and to prevent unwanted spacing when you use the image for the web.

I'm glad I could have helped out and best of luck in your design mate!